# What does !* mean in tcsh shell?

Tags: linux, shell, command, csh

such as command

```
myCommand !* &
```

`&` is run in bg, but what is `!*` ? Can not find it anywhere, c shell is not used anywhere nowadays ...

Comment: It is documented in the [csh man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) if you search for `!` enough.

Comment: you are right, but after reading the man page, I still don't get it. but the answer below made everything clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`!` is the start of a history substitution. `!*` means "all the arguments from the preceding command".

So if you first do:

```
echo foo bar baz
```

and then do

```
myCommand !* &
```

the second command is equivalent to:

```
myCommand foo bar baz &
```

If this is part of an alias definition, the "preceding" command is actually the invocation of the alias. So if you write

```
alias myc 'myCommand !* &'
```

Then writing

```
myc foo bar baz
```

is expanded into

```
myCommand foo bar baz &
```

Comment: Why if I do `echo foo bar` and then `echo !*` I get `echo foo bar (newline) foo bar`? Why not just  `foo bar`?

Comment: When you type a command with history, it shows you the command with the history filled in.